# Getting 'No module named clip' error in stable-diffusion's webui.bat, how to fix it?

Tags: python, openai-api, clip, stable-diffusion

It happened in my installation of stable-diffusion

I have installed Clip using `pip install clip`

and in Python.exe, `import clip` is successful.

and when I run  `pip list` , clip  is  there.

but, when I run stable diffusion's webui.bat, an error pop up:

```
Launching Web UI with arguments:
No module 'xformers'. Proceeding without it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Software\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-1.2.1\launch.py", line 375, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:\Software\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-1.2.1\launch.py", line 366, in start
    import webui
  File "C:\Software\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-1.2.1\webui.py", line 37, in <module>
    from modules import extra_networks, ui_extra_networks_checkpoints
  File "C:\Software\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-1.2.1\modules\ui_extra_networks_checkpoints.py", line 5, in <module>
    from modules import shared, ui_extra_networks, sd_models
  File "C:\Software\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-1.2.1\modules\ui_extra_networks.py", line 8, in <module>
    from modules.images import read_info_from_image
  File "C:\Software\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-1.2.1\modules\images.py", line 21, in <module>
    from modules import sd_samplers, shared, script_callbacks, errors
  File "C:\Software\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-1.2.1\modules\sd_samplers.py", line 1, in <module>
    from modules import sd_samplers_compvis, sd_samplers_kdiffusion, shared
  File "C:\Software\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-1.2.1\modules\sd_samplers_kdiffusion.py", line 5, in <module>    import k_diffusion.sampling
  File "C:\Software\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-1.2.1\repositories\k-diffusion\k_diffusion\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import augmentation, config, evaluation, external, gns, layers, models, sampling, utils
  File "C:\Software\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-1.2.1\repositories\k-diffusion\k_diffusion\evaluation.py", line 6, in <module>
    import clip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clip'
```

as the error code above, in evaluation.py, when `import clip` is called,  No module named 'clip'

how could I fix it.?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

i think the CLIP you have installed is https://pypi.org/project/clip/

This is not the CLIP you want,
You want the Clip that is from OpenAI,

!pip install git+https://github.com/openai/CLIP.git

This should help you.